# Best way to store tags or categories like Stack Overflow

Tags: database-design

I have a question web application which allows users to ask questions on specific things.  I am developing a tag style labeling for each question just like stack overflow.  When I associate each post with categories or tags, I was wondering what is the best way to store this. Here is what I would guess would be an ideal way to do this:

-Create a column in the sql database to store either a serialized json object or simply just a comma separated line with the IDs of the categories that the question pertains to.

I feel with this approach it will be hard to search questions according to a specific tag because it will have to parse the categories column for each question which seems like it would not be ideal.  What is a good way to architect this feature to fit searching well, but also keep the schema fairly simple (keep in mind, my main goal is to make the tags as similar to stackoverflow as possible)?

Comment: Note that this question has very little if anything to do with C# or ASP.NET, this is more about database design. To that, I say 1 question can have many tags. 1 tag can have many questions. Therefore, you would be well served with a data schema to reflect that many to many relationship. 1:M:1.

Comment: thanks, I will definitely remember to tag things better!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, to keep it simply why not just follow the normalized approach with three tables:

Questiond(QId, name)

Tag (tagId, name)

Tag-per-topic (QId,tagId)

very simple....

Comment: when I start having millions of questions with tags associated with all of this, wont the database be very large? will that matter?

Comment: well, each tag will only be ONCE in the tagtable so that will be small and efficient. The tag-per-topic contains only integer (ID) fields so it will be relatively small and quite fast. Proper indexing will do the rest. It will be smaller and faster than storing redundant tag strings for sure. In the end, databases are meant to handle a lot of data efficiently. Thats what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is with foreign keys.

Have one table that stores the question/item with its unique ID.
(item_ID, info1, info2, info3 ...)

Have another table that stores all the possible tags and their unique ID.
(tag_ID, tag_name)

Have one last table that links the two together.
(item_ID,tag_ID)

Answer (score 1):

just a simple [many-to-many](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relation?

For example:

```
table: [questions]
[TableId][name]
'1' - 'general'

table: [Tags]
[TagId][name]
'99' - 'c#'

table: [QuestionsTagged]
[TableId][TagId]
'1' - '99'
```

Then link them together with [foreign key constraints](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Foreign_key)

Answer (score 0):

Each post would have an ID in some table with whatever you plan to include.  Let's call it 'posts'.

Each post tag would be in another table with post_id and the tag (and any audit columns you might like) 'post_tags'.

You, as an administrator can then (optionally) add records to a 'tags' lookup table for tags that are popular enough for you to want to define them well, a la https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info.